# python lxml: how to get text from a element which has a child element

Tags: python, lxml

I want to extract sometext from the html code, but the following doesn't r
eturn sometext, instead it return "\n". So how to get sometest?

```
a=html.fromstring("""
<p class="clearfix">
<i class="xueli"></i>
sometext
</p>
""")
a.find(".//i").getparent().text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.text`, use `text_content()` method:

```
In [5]: a.find(".//i").getparent().text_content().strip()
Out[5]: 'sometext'
```

Or, you can get to the *following text sibling* of the `i` element:

```
In [6]: a.xpath(".//i/following-sibling::text()")[0].strip()
Out[6]: 'sometext'
```