# How to get the raw text from lxml element with Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to get the following inline text strings from the root element.

```
from lxml import etree

root = root = etree.fromstring(
'''<p>
    text-first
    <span>
        Child 1
    </span>
    text-middle
    <span>
        Child 2
    </span>
    text-last
</p>''')
```

`root.text` only returns the "text-first" including newlines

```
>>> build_text_list = etree.XPath("//text()")

>>> texts = build_text_list(root)
>>>
>>> texts
['\n    text-first\n    ', '\n        Child 1\n    ', '\n    text-middle\n    ', '\n        Child 2\n    ', '\n    text-last\n']
>>>
>>> for t in texts:
...     print t
...     print t.__dict__
...

    text-first

{'_parent': <Element p at 0x10140f638>, 'is_attribute': False, 'attrname': None, 'is_text': True, 'is_tail': False}

        Child 1

{'_parent': <Element span at 0x10140be18>, 'is_attribute': False, 'attrname': None, 'is_text': True, 'is_tail': False}

    text-middle

{'_parent': <Element span at 0x10140be18>, 'is_attribute': False, 'attrname': None, 'is_text': False, 'is_tail': True}

        Child 2

{'_parent': <Element span at 0x10140be60>, 'is_attribute': False, 'attrname': None, 'is_text': True, 'is_tail': False}

    text-last

{'_parent': <Element span at 0x10140be60>, 'is_attribute': False, 'attrname': None, 'is_text': False, 'is_tail': True}
>>>
>>> root.xpath("./p/following-sibling::text()") # following https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832753/1677041
[]
```

So, how can I get the `text-first/middle/last` parts from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

etree is perfectly capable of this:

```py
from lxml import etree

root: etree.Element = etree.fromstring(
'''<p>
    text-first
    <span>
        Child 1
    </span>
    text-middle
    <span>
        Child 2
    </span>
    text-last
</p>''')

print(
    root.text,
    root[0].tail,
    root[1].tail,
)
```

All elements are lists of their subelements, so the indexing here refers to the 2 `<span>` elements. The tail attribute of any element contains the text directly after that element.

It will of course include newlines, so you might want to strip() the results: `root.text.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Your initial guess, `//text()` means: select all text nodes, no matter where in the document they are. What you actually would like to select are text nodes if they are an immediate child of `p`, or alternatively if they are not children of `span`.

The most precise answer given the input document you are showing is `/p/text()`:

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring(
'''<p>
text-first
<span>
    Child 1
</span>
text-middle
<span>
    Child 2
</span>
text-last
</p>''')

>>> etree.XPath("/p/text()")(root)
['\n    text-first\n    ', '\n    text-middle\n    ', '\n    text-last\n']
```

---

Your own solution `child::text()` means: select text nodes if they are a child of the current context node. It works because XPath expressions are in this case evaluated using the root element, `p`, as context. That is why simply `text()` also works.

```
>>> etree.XPath("text()")(root)
['\n    text-first\n    ', '\n    text-middle\n    ', '\n    text-last\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, `xpath` saves me in the end.

```
>>> root.xpath('child::text()')
['\n    text-first\n    ', '\n    text-middle\n    ', '\n    text-last\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(root.xpath('normalize-space(//*)'))
```

Comment: This returns contains the span text content and not my expectation, thanks any way!